# pyqt4: How to change button event without adding a new event?

Tags: python, events, signals, pyqt4

I have a click button that I want to change events when the button is pressed. A minimal version of the existing code looks like this:

```
# Event that happens the first time
def first_event(self):
    button.setText("Second Event")
    button.clicked.connect(second_event)

# Event that happens the second time
def second_event(self):
    button.setText("First Event")
    button.clicked.connect(first_event)

button = QtGui.QPushButton("First Event")
button.clicked.connect(first_event)
```

Unfortunately, instead of **changing** the event that happens, it simply **adds** and event to the clicked signal, meaning that the following happens:

First button press - calls first_event

Second button press - calls first_event and second_event

Third button press - calls first_event twice and second_event

etc...

My desired behavior would be to have the button **change functions when it is pressed**, so that the resulting behavior would be:

First button press - calls first_event

Second button press - calls second_event

Third button press - calls first_event

etc...

Is there a way to make it so that it changes the click event instead of adding a new one? Is there a way to remove events after the fact?

Comment: You should try to explain what specific problem you are trying to solve with this. In all likelihood, it's not the right way of going about it.

Comment: All I want is a button that changes functions when it is clicked. Think of a play button on a TV remote: when you press it once, it plays, but if you press it again, it pauses. It changes it's usage when it's pressed.

Comment: In that case, all you need is a simple flag to record the current state.

Comment: That would require combining my two distinct functions, or creating a wrapper function from which to call the two functions.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to separate old events from signals using the `disconnect()` method. Here is an edited version that accomplishes what I originally wanted to do:

```
# Event that happens the first time
def first_event(self):
    button.setText("Second Event")
    button.clicked.disconnect()
    button.clicked.connect(second_event)

# Event that happens the second time
def second_event(self):
    button.setText("First Event")
    button.clicked.disconnect()
    button.clicked.connect(first_event)

button = QtGui.QPushButton("First Event")
button.clicked.connect(first_event)
```

It's worth noting that instead of doing this, I eventually did what ekhumoro mentioned in the comments, and created a wrapper function with a flag to record the current state, and then call `first_event()` or `second_event()` based on the value of the flag.